# Using React Router to invoke state/functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a material-ui drawer, when the user clicks a button to open the drawer I'd like the url to change without a navigation actually happening, if someone visits the url (such as url.com/drawer) they'll land on the page with the drawer already open (or at least in the process of opening).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put `?drawer=open` as a query string parameter rather than have it be a dedicated route. When the button is clicked, navigate to the current route with `?drawer=open` appended, either by having the button actually being a styled [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link), or using [history.push](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history).